# Cocoa bindings and KVC with CGColorRef

Tags: core-graphics, cocoa-bindings, key-value-coding

I'm trying to bind a `CGColorRef` on one of my objects to the "`shadowColor`" property of a `CALayer`. Unfortunately, I haven't been able to figure this out - it's probably something really simple!

The CGColorRef is implemented as a property:

```
@property (readwrite) CGColorRef labelShadowColor;
```

My binding is straight forward too:

```
[aLayer bind:@"shadowColor" toObject:aScreen withKeyPath:@"labelShadowColor" options:nil];
```

Where I'm coming unstuck is `valueForUndefinedKey:` - how would I implement this for a `CGColorRef`? I'm currently getting the boilerplate:

```
2009-08-09 03:13:50.056 Hyperspaces[33161:a0f] An uncaught exception was raised
2009-08-09 03:13:50.060 Hyperspaces[33161:a0f] [<HSScreen 0x100533930> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key labelShadowColor.
2009-08-09 03:13:50.064 Hyperspaces[33161:a0f] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<HSScreen 0x100533930> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key labelShadowColor.'
```

I can work around this by putting an `NSColor` property on both ends and setting the `CALayer`'s "`shadowColor`" manually whenever the color is changed, but that seems inelegant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so here's a tip that I missed (and how I solved it):

You can't synthesize CGColorRefs (`@synthesize someProperty;`) - you need to declare the property `@dynamic` and implement the getters/setters, like so:

```
@dynamic labelShadowColor;
- (CGColorRef)labelShadowColor {
    return labelShadowColor;
}

- (void)setLabelShadowColor:(CGColorRef)aShadowColor {
    if (CGColorEqualToColor(labelShadowColor,aShadowColor)) return;

    CGColorRelease(labelShadowColor);
    if (aShadowColor != NULL) {
        labelShadowColor = CGColorRetain(aShadowColor);
    }
}
```

Then you'll also need to define `valueForUndefinedKey:` in your class:

```
- (id)valueForUndefinedKey:(NSString *)key {
  if ([key isEqualToString:@"labelShadowColor"]) {
    return (id)self.labelShadowColor;
  }

  return [super valueForUndefinedKey:key];
}
```

Once these two things were done, my bindings sprang into action!

Comment: This, amazingly, works.  WTF would you need to declare `valueForUndefinedKey`, when in fact - it is defined?  Totally counterintuitive.  How did you figure this out?

Comment: Honestly, it was close to 4 years ago. Pretty sure this was a bug/detail of how CG* types worked with properties at the time, but I don't remember specifically why/how I came to this conclusion. Does it still work? I wouldn't imagine it's necessary on iOS (just use UIColor).